# Undefined reference error while using json-c

Tags: c, json, json-c

I want to use json-c in my program. While compiling (linking) I'm getting errors:

```
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0xf): undefined reference to `json_object_new_object'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x1c): undefined reference to `json_object_new_string'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x2b): undefined reference to `json_object_new_int'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x3a): undefined reference to `json_object_new_boolean'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x4a): undefined reference to `json_object_new_double'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x52): undefined reference to `json_object_new_array'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x5f): undefined reference to `json_object_new_string'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x6e): undefined reference to `json_object_new_string'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x7b): undefined reference to `json_object_new_string'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x8b): undefined reference to `json_object_array_add'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0x96): undefined reference to `json_object_array_add'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0xa1): undefined reference to `json_object_array_add'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0xb3): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0xc3): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0xd3): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0xe5): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0xf5): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
parsejson.c:(.text.startup+0xfd): undefined reference to `json_object_to_json_string'
```

I've json-c and my program on the same folder and included it using `#include <json-c/json.h>`.

Comment: Show your compilation command line.  Are you listing the library after `parsejson.c` or `parsejson.o`, whichever you list on the linking command line?  Have you built the json-c library?  Are you linking with it?

Comment: no i'm just using command "gcc parsejson.c", json-c is a third party lib but i've included using #include

Comment: The header provides declarations.  It does not provide the implementations, usually.  You need to link with the library, which you need to compile and perhaps install (depending on whether it's shared or static).  Doesn't the README for the library tell you about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking statically, gcc brings the symbols that are already encountered. So if you are passing `-ljson` before your source files, gcc will take the static library and then eventually does not really need anything out of it.
So you should put the libraries to link against *after* your code.

Though you have not shared what your compilation command line say, I would recommend trying something like:

```
$ gcc -g -v -Wall -std=gnu99 -static -L/path/to/compiled/library parsejson.c -o parsejson -ljson
```

Comment: You would not use `-L` with the entire path to `parsejson.c`; you might use the full path to `parsejson.c`, or you might use `-L` with a directory that contains the compiled json-c library.  Or you missed a space between the metacharacter `>` and the name `parsejson.c` in your command line.

Comment: it's not working says bash: -L: No such file or directory

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, I missed a space between `>` and `parsejson.c`. I will edit that now. Thanks.

Comment: @Sparsh: I hope you are not using `<` and `>`. (You are supposed to omit that out)

Comment: @WedaPashi  yes i've omit < and  > but still getting error

Comment: Suggestion: use a path such as `-L/path/to/compiled/library` rather than risk using shell metacharacters, especially important ones like `<` or `>`.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this:

```
#include "../json-c/json.h"
```

because if you user  the compiler will search the json.h in standard libraries.Obviously,it isn't in the standard library.if you use what I have told you ,the compiler will search the json.h in curent workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`gcc parsejson.c -o parsejson -ljson-c`

to compile and use

`#include "json-c/json.h"`

to include the header